# Django Admin remove "today" on a DateField() field

Tags: django, django-admin

Anyone know of a way to remove the "Today" option as it appears in the Django Admin? I would like to retain the clickable JavaScript calendar, I just have no need for the "Today" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just hide it with css.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    display: none
}
</style>
```

If you want this done everywhere, I would create a static file for css and load it in your admin base template - a central place for overrides such as this one.

Comment: Works for me. That was my last resort; I just didn't know if there was an undocumented option for DateField() that hid this.

Comment: It didn't work for me; django 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but it might work to put a space in the msgstr in /django/contrib/admin/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po:

```
#: media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js:133
#: media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js:182
msgid "Today"
msgstr " "
```

Then re-compile the language files by running:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems slightly hacky, though. :]

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me (Django v1.10). It removes both the 'Today' and 'Now' link

```
django.jQuery(window).load(function(){
var shortcutsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("datetimeshortcuts");
for (var i = 0; i < shortcutsDiv.length; i++) {
    var link = shortcutsDiv[i].firstElementChild;
    link.remove();
    }
});
```